# Web API controller returns empty JSON even if returned var is not empty

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, controller

In my API, I have to return a json composed of 2 distinct objects, one is a unique entity and the other a list. When I return each separatly there is no problem, but when I try to return them as a single json, the result is empty, even though my var in the return ok(var) contains what is supposed to be returned.

The controller looks like this:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetOne(int id)
{
    var x = Service.GetOne(id);
    return Ok(x)
}
```

(If I put a breakpoint on the return line, I can see that x contains the single object and the list that I want in my json)

"Service" is where I merge the 2 objects by caling a model constructor that takes the single object and the list as input, it looks like this:

```
public class mergedObject
{
    IEnumerable<SingleObject> y;
    IEnumerable<ListObject> z;

    public mergedObject GetOne(int Id)
    {
        mergedObject x = new mergedObject(RepoSingleObject.getOne(Id) a, 
                                             RepoList.GetAll(Id) b)

        this.y = a
        this.z = b
    }
```

It calls the corresponding repository(which contains the sql query) for each object and I know this part is working, since like I said earlier, I can properly return each object individually.

The console returns absolutely no error, I did everything the same way as with the individual objects, except for the merging and when I use breakpoints everything seems to go fine, but yet, using postman to test it, I always get an empty return. Does anyone have an explanation?

EDIT

The controller is derived from ApiController + added full definition of the mergedObject class up there. I use IEnumerable even on the single object because I reuse some part of the code where this single element is in fact a list, so I figured it would only be a list of 1 element and wouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: Just a FYI, using wrong `[HttpGet]` attribute. That one is for MVC not Web API `System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute`. Also confirm that the controller is derived from `ApiController`

Comment: Show definition of `mergedObject`. Problem could be with how it is being serialized.

Comment: Are the two objects accessible in mergedObject via public properties (with a get) ?

Comment: @J.Loscos In mergedObject I access them direclty by calling the repository which sends the sql query, but I do have a get for each of them. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: `mergedObject` has no public properties to serialize.

Comment: @GabStPier what should the desired JSON look like?

Comment: @Nkosi It should have the properties of the single object listed, then the attributes of the object in list, repeated for the number of object in the list.

Comment: @Nkosi You were rigth, all that was missing was to make the class serializable. I thought that somehow by merging 2 already serializable classes it would work. Thank you!